# SQLite Android - getting month

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I´m trying to get all the records within the month.

my date is stored as a TEXT(tryed DATE) and a string in android

my method for get the current date:

```
   private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

and my Cursor:

```
public Cursor getCursor(){
        return db.rawQuery("Select strftime('%m', " + CN_DATE + ") as valMonth from " + TABLE_NAME + " where valMonth = '05' GROUP BY valMonth)" , null);
    }
```

Error: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `)` at the end of your query string. Remove it.

Also remove the `GROUP BY valMonth` if you want to get all records for a given month and not just one aggregate record.

If you query by month extensively, consider storing the month value directly in a column and do your queries on that for much better query performance.

Comment: thx for ur answer !  but now it says: column '_id' does not exist 
there is a way to store the resulto of the query in a variable? for use it on another query?

Comment: Where exactly is that exception thrown? Are you using a `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: yes i'm using CursorAdapter for fill a custom listview

Comment: Then your cursor must include a column with the name `_id`. You can e.g. add `rowid AS _id` to your selection to get one.

Comment: it works!! thx a lot ... how can i put your answer for the right one or give points or something? i'm new at this...

Comment: Click the checkmark next to the answer to choose one as the "correct" one, giving the answerer +15 rep.